# there exists a hypersurface H ⊂ X such that X \ H is Stein and L is trivial over X \ H

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

"Suppose that X is a compact projective manifold
equipped with a K¨ahler metric ω. Let L be a holomorphic line bundle
In general, there exists a hypersurface H ⊂ X such that
X \ H is Stein and L is trivial over X \ H" this is a result demailly states in the paper

[Singular hermitian metric on positive line bundle](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/bayreuth.pdf) .Can this be proved in case of compact riemann surface using elementary methods.

Comment: The "projective" hypothesis subsumes the Kahler hypothesis. Writing $L = L_1 \otimes L_2^{-1}$ for very ample $L_1$ and $L_2$ arising from projective embeddings of $X$, there are global sections $s_i$ of $L_i$ corresponding to hyperplane sections, so $H_i = \{s_i = 0\}$ has complement $U_i$ that is affine algebraic and hence Stein (being closed in an affine space) with $L_i$ trivial on $U_i$. Then set $H=H_1 \cup H_2$, so $X-H=U_1 \cap U_2$ is closed in $U_1 \times U_2$ and hence is Stein. Clearly $L|_U$ is trivial.

Comment: It depends on what definition of Stein you are using.If you mean existence of strictly plurisubharmonic exhaustion function then one can give an elementary construction of such a function on any open Riemann surface .Any holomorphic vector bundle over an open Riemann surface is trivial .

Comment: i am not sure what definition of stein demailly is using,all I am trying to do is adapt demailly's method in the above paper to prove the hormander's l^2 existence theorem for riemann surface.

Comment: He is using the existence of strictly psh exhaustion function.You will find all of this in the book I mentioned previously

Answer (score 3):

As $X$ is projective, consider an embedding of $X$ into projective space and let $L$ be the line bundle corresponding to the hyperplanes in that projective space (which is the line bundle whose sections give the embedding). Let $H$ be a hyperplane section. By the definition of $L$ it is trivial on $X\setminus H$ and $X\setminus H$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ which is Stein (I think regardless what definition you use).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a compact connected Riemann surface and let $L$ be a line bundle.

Let $H$ be any non-empty finite set of points of $X$. Then $X\backslash H$ is Stein (by a deep theorem of Behnke and Stein (1948) according to Wikipedia).

Now choose $H$ such that $L$ is trivial on $X\backslash H$. (Let $U\subset X$ be a trivializing open for $L$ and let $H$ be the complement of $X$ in $U$ for instance. If $L$ is trivial, choose $H  = \{pt\}$.)

Depending on your definition of a hypersurface (whether it should be connected or not), this shows that there exists a hypersurface $H$ with the sought properties.